# How to parse a HTML page including hidden tags

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to parse some web pages for future use. For parsing webpages, I've used different modules like urllib, lxml, BeautifulSoup, HTMLParser to reach my goal.

I didn't meet any problem while parsing web pages until I faced the hidden  tags.

When I opened the page with a chrome browser and used the developer tools to see elements of page, I was able to see the `<embed>` part of the code:

```
 <embed type="..." src="..." ID="..." >
```

and simply can copy/paste manually.

I need to parse `ID` from this hidden tag. Why can I parse this part from the site by using python? Any way to parse these hidden parts?

I know it's not possible to see some code parts like php and asp in the html source but I suppose it's not the case.

Comment: What has parsing to do with caching? Caching is the task of a front-end proxy dealing with caching issues. What are you actually trying to solve? Your description is more than weird.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand either. Can you clarify what you want to do?

Comment: Sorry for my english. Just I'd like to collect a bunch of photos from several websites. The source links of photos are in <embed> tags. I mean <embed type="" src="" ID="www.xxx.com/asdsadasfgdsgdfs.jpg">. But in my case, somehow the site owner had made it hidden and I cant see these codes in page-source (CTRL+U in chrome). My question, why I can't parse this part of html source although I am able to see them in "developer tools(like firebug)" of the web browser.

Comment: If you don't see them when viewing source, then they're not there. They aren't hidden--they are not in HTML source code. More than likely, they are being added after the fact via javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "hidden" code is probably generated by JavaScript at runtime.

You might have better luck finding out how the JavaScript works and where it gets its data (the URLs) than attempting to have something run the script and then parse the resulting DOM tree...