# script hide some elements in html document

Tags: javascript

i want to parse a web page using HPPLE .my html page looks like this :

```
<table dir = "rtl ..">
<tbody>
<script src = "get.aspx?type=js&file=ajax&rev=3"..>
<script language = "JavaScript"......>
<script>..</script>
<tr>
<td id = "jm0x1"...>
<td id = "jm0x2"...>
<tr>
<tr>...<tr>
<tr>...<tr>
a lot of <tr> here....
......
</tbody>
```

i can see all elements  after < script>..< /script> with the developer tools in safari or firefox but when i download the html page all tags after < script>..< /script> are not downloaded .i think they are being added after the fact via javascript but the question:how to get theme? this is the source code of the web page [source](http://kooora.com/?c=6423) and this is also some one have the same problem [some one have the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383623/how-to-parse-a-html-page-including-hidden-tags)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Firebug, you should be able to right-click on the html tag in the Firebug window (HTML tab) and select "Copy HTML" and paste that into a text editor.

Comment: thanks JackWilson but i want to download and parse this html from web i work on iphone app